# FileInfo.Length != sum of all line length

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a progress bar for big file's reading.
 I set the progress bar's maximum value to `FileInfo.Length`, I read each line using `StreamReader.ReadLine` and compute the sum of each line length (with `String.Length`) to set the progress bar's current value.

What I noticed is that there is a difference between the file's total length and the sum of the length of each line. For example :
`FileInfo.Length`= 25577646
Sum of all line length = 25510563

Why is there such a difference ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't adding the end-of-lines. It could be from 1 to 4 bytes, depending on the encoding or if it is a `\n` or a `\r` or a `\r\n` (1 byte = UTF8 + `\n`, 4 bytes = UTF16 + `\r\n`)

Note that with `ReadLine` it isn't possible to check which end-of-line (`\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` it encountered)

From [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n")

Other problem: if your file is UTF8, then C# char length is different from byte length: `è` is one char in C# (that uses UTF16), 2 chars in UTF8. You could:

```
int len = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(line);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I just added 2 to each String.length and I have the exact same result as `FileInfo.Length`.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems here:

- `string.Length` gives you the number of *characters* in each string, whereas `FileInfo.Length` gives you the number of *bytes*. Those can be very different things, depending on the characters and the encoding used
- You're not including the line breaks (typically `\n` or `\r\n`) as those are removed when reading lines with `TextReader.ReadLine`

In terms of what to do about this...

- You presumably know the file's encoding, so you *could* convert each line back into bytes by calling `Encoding.GetBytes` to account for that difference. It would be pretty wasteful to do this though.
- If you know the line break used by the file, you could just add the relevant number of bytes for each line you read
- You could keep a reference to the underlying stream and use `Stream.Position` to detect how far through the file you've actually read. That won't necessarily be the same as the amount of data you've *processed* though, as the `StreamReader` will have a buffer. (So you may well "see" that the `Stream` has read all the data even though you haven't processed all the lines yet.)

The last idea is probably the cleanest, IMO.